# function pointers c++ Why is the output = 1 why is the address of the function not being printed?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

Why is the output  = 1 why is the address of the function not being printed?

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;
int area(){
    return 4;
    }
int main(){
  int (*p2)();
  p2 = &area;
  cout<<p2<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```